# Problem when running a discord music bot from Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I have been uploading a discord bot written in python to Heroku. I have made it able to play music using the codes as follow:

```
async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options": "-vn"}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, executable="./ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
```

However, as I try to play music from discord, the log page of heroku displays the following:

```
2022-01-10T09:19:31.265707+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command play:
2022-01-10T09:19:31.266951+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-01-10T09:19:31.266983+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 167, in wrapped
2022-01-10T09:19:31.266983+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.266990+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/music.py", line 37, in play
2022-01-10T09:19:31.266991+00:00 app[worker.1]: source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, executable="./ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267000+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 451, in from_probe
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267001+00:00 app[worker.1]: return cls(source, bitrate=bitrate, codec=codec, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267008+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 383, in __init__
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267013+00:00 app[worker.1]: super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267015+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 152, in __init__
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267016+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._process: subprocess.Popen = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267017+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 166, in _spawn_process
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267018+00:00 app[worker.1]: process = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, **subprocess_kwargs)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267036+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267036+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267036+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267036+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267054+00:00 app[worker.1]: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './ffmpeg.exe'
```

I figure out the source of error should be

```
2022-01-10T09:19:31.267054+00:00 app[worker.1]: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './ffmpeg.exe'
```

But I'm not sure why it is happening as the bot plays music perfectly when I run the bot directly from the computer.

I'm really confused and don't know how to solve the problem. Thanks very much in advance for anyone who may provide some suggestions.

Comment: HI, you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146519/how-to-use-the-heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-for-python

Comment: Wow installing that buildpack does solve the problem entirely! Thanks really much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment from Ishan, the problem can be solved perfectly by installing the buildpack of ffmpeg in heroku as shown in [How to use the Heroku buildpack ffmpeg for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146519/how-to-use-the-heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-for-python)
For anyone who may encounter the same problem as I did, here is the code I type

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
git push heroku master
```

in your heroku directory.
The credit goes to Ishan who kind-heartedly commented the link and the one who post the solution to the above StackOverflow post.

Comment: You shouldn't have an `ffmpeg.exe` on Heroku at all. That looks like a _Windows_ binary. If it's committed to your repository I suggest you remove it, e.g. via `git rm --cached ffmpeg.exe`, then `git commit`.

Comment: Yes I have done so too. Thanks a lot for your help!